# Изменение введенного значения элемента динамического указательного массива в Си

Tags: c

Столкнулся с проблемой: не могу понять, как присвоить значение элементу динамического указательного массива.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main()
{
    int n, m, i, j;
    printf("Count of lines: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Count of columns: ");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    int *ms = (int*) malloc(n*m*sizeof(int));
for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j<m; j++)
                {
                    printf("%d %d : ",i+1,j+1);
                    scanf("%d", (ms + i*m + j));
                }

            printf(" %d\n",min);
        }
}
```

Не понятно, как изменить значение, так как

```
(ms + i*m + j) = 10;
```

не работает. Что делать?

Comment: Что такое `<malloc.h>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделайте проще:

```
int **ms = (int**) malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    ms[i] = (int*)malloc(m*sizeof(int));
```

После этого `ms[i][j]` - вполне корректная конструкция :)

Answer (score 1):

Звездочку забыли:

```
*(ms + i*m + j) = 10;
```

Или так:

```
ms[i*m + j] = 10;
```